# Library 'scala-2.10.0-RC1 not used' thrown by IntelliJ integrating a Play 2 app

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I've just generated a fresh Play! application, version 2.1-RC1.

This one includes two Scala compiler/library couple:

- Scala 2.9.2
- Scala 2.10.0-RC1

The whole well compiles within IntelliJ IDEA 12 but a **warning** occurs as the image shows it:

[image: Complains about Scala library not used]

It would seem so that another compiler is used instead 2.10.0-RC1.

However, my Scala facet is configured as this:

[image: Scala Facet configured with 2.10.0-RC1]

**What might be the warning cause?**

I precise that I've got also a Scala variable environment (used for shell Scala commands) configured to point to scala-2.10.0-RC2, but I well imagine that IntelliJ is based on library that user indicates in Scala Facet.

Comment: Was that project generated from Play command-line?

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes, I've generated it with firstly `play new MyApp`, then `play`(for SBT shell), then `idea with-sources=yes` to generate IDEA necessary files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove that .jar from the libraries, it's not used because it's redundantly generated by IntelliJ SBT plubin.

Comment: This is what I've just done :) I've also just precised the final scala version to be used into sbt configuration: scalaversion 2.10.0, accessible from repository/local. If I figure out well, SBT currently needs scala 2.9.2 whereas it is configured (thanks to the sbt-play plugin) to compile Play app with 2.10.0? Can I remove 2.9.2 jar also or this might lead to some potential issues with SBT?  Thanks :)

Comment: I had problem with this one bit. Some play plugins were adding the dependency with 2.9.2, I had to change them manually.