# Scala Upgrade procedure, for the Typesafe/Scala stack under IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, scala-2.10, typesafe-stack

Scala is an awesome language.  And IntelliJ 12's integration with the Typesafe stack (Scala, Akka, and the Play Framework) is equally impressive.

But, the upgrade process for upgrading the version of Scala version under IntelliJ isn't particularly clear.  I'm using Play 2.0, IntelliJ 12 and currently Scala 2.91.  My first attempt to upgrade to Scala 2.10 didn't go well:  pre-existing Play projects are still fixated on using Scala 2.91 libraries and the 2.91 compiler.  Attempting to create new Play projects and execute the "idea" command: generated IJ project files are generated for 2.91.

Even if I explicitly remove the 2.91 .jars and add the 2.10 .jars, It seems that I am still stuck with the 2.91 Scala compiler.  There just has to be a simpler way to upgrade Scala, and still have the full Typesafe stack building and launching under IJ 12 ... I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Scala 2.10 with Play you will need to upgrade to Play 2.1.

Comment: So if I understand correctly ... I can install play 2.1, upgrade scala 2.10 and then play's "idea" command will properly initialize the project for use within IJ?  I ran into issues where it was complaining about my version of SBT but, if you have in fact, had some luck with this -- I can give it another whirl and see if I may have missed something.

Comment: Yup!  And Play 2.1 just came out.  Make sure you read the [Migration Guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration).

Comment: Aha, somehow I managed to miss the migration guide on my first attempt.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I'll report back on how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I am getting closer to getting this to work but am still having an issue with the Play "idea" command.  After issuing a "play idea", ${project_root}/target contains a "scala-2.10" directory.  But ${project_root}/project/target contains a "scala-2.9.2" directory.  I can run play from the command-line just fine but IJ 12 is not picking up the scala files that are being generated from the templates (hence resulting in compiler errors when references views from the controller).  Also looking at the libraries ... All of the 2.9.2 libraries are showing up along the 2.10 libraries.

Comment: I had to delete the `.idea*` and `*.iml` files, then do a `play clean idea` and then re-open the project.

Comment: Still no love ... I even created a brand new project (play new test ... then play idea) and I'm getting *both* scala-2.9.2 appearing in one target subdirectory within the project and scala-2.10 in another target subdirectory of the project.  And when I open the project in IJ, things are still completely hosed.  I'm pretty baffled at this point.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that this one is biting me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248159/library-scala-2-10-0-rc1-not-used-thrown-by-intellij-integrating-a-play-2-app

Comment: It looks like I need to *manually* remove the old Scala library and add the new one (and be sure that external compilation is disabled).  It seems to be working now though!

Comment: Given the union of your suggestion and all supporting commentary has led me to a solution (minus some clunkiness with IJ and some curious files that are being generated in one of the target directories) -- I'm accepting this answer.  Thanks again!