# Play 2.0 and IDEA. Missed javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean dependencies

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I created new play 2.1 Java project using Intellij IDEA, and when I open `Build.scala` file to manage dependencies I see that IDEA cannot resolve some dependencies and `play.Project` class. But project compiles fine and I can run it in browser. Where can be problem?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I tried to re-create project using play command line (as suggested @biesior and @maba), so now I don't have any issue with dependencies, but all scala code is not resolved(for example in templates code). Also I noted that I have error in `Project Structure` menu: 
[image]

Comment: Did you run `play idea` first?

Comment: @maba I created project using IDEA wizard (`play 2.0` plugin). And I can run my project on browser from IDEA. So my project 100% "idealized"

Comment: First: DON'T create Play project with Idea, use command line, idealize  it (as @maba wrote) and finally open in Idea (open, DON'T import...), Second if app compiles... don't care about dependencies in IDE :)

Comment: @biesior Yes, I tried to recreate project using `play new` and all dependencies resolved. It's mean IDEA play 2.0 plugin still have many bugs?

Comment: @biesior write your comment as answer to the question. I'll accept it

Comment: To resolve your dependency issue: Just remove the unnecessary Scala version from the "Libraries" and add the correct again to `yourprojectname-build`. Delete the one that is already there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First:** DON'T create Play project with Idea, use command line, idealize it (as @maba wrote) and finally open in Idea (open, DON'T import...),

**Second:** if app compiles... don't care about dependencies in IDE :)

**Note:** I wouldn't blame Idea's plugin - it was created for Play 2.0 and modularization (`javaCore`, `javaEbean` etc.) is incorporated in Play 2.1... Actually Play 2+ is quite fresh thing and I think that we will need to wait a little to get perfect support in IDEs. Finally I'm a fan of 'JetBrainiacs' for relatively fast response for Play's changes :)

Comment: sorry, but I have another issue. See updated answer. If you want I can create new question, but I'll accept your answer anyway (as I promised).

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248159/library-scala-2-10-0-rc1-not-used-thrown-by-intellij-integrating-a-play-2-app to be honest I'm still working in 2.0.x projects, so I don;t meet these warnings (probably soon I will :) )